# Concat simple misque

Tags: javascript, concatenation

When I wrote this, I assumed the 2nd console log would be an array of 4.  I was under the impression that my code would take whom and then concatinate that to the first console.log of an array of 2 and then the next iteration would be an array of 4 since it is concat.

```
let player1Hand = [];



function drawDeck(whom, whichDeck, howMany) {
    whom = whom.concat(whichDeck.splice(0, howMany));
    console.log(whom);
}

drawDeck(player1Hand, genericDeck, 2);
drawDeck(player1Hand, genericDeck, 2);
```

instead the console log is first array  and then the 2nd log is a sepperate array... I think as I wrote this I rubber ducked myself.

Comment: What is `genericDeck`? Keep in mind that `splice` mutates the array. The `genericDeck` passed in as `whichDeck` is mutated every time you call the function. Maybe you want to copy it with `.slice()` before `.splice`?

Comment: I realized my problem was I was not exiting the scope.  I was not setting player1Hand outside the function to be inline with the first itteration.   genericDeck was a second .js file that had 5 card arrays put in to test.  Pretty much as soon as I finished figuring out how to specifically ask the question light dawned... i was creating 2 sepparate values to player1Hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem you have is using concat which returns a new array and not adding the items to the current array that you already have. Setting it to the old value does not update the reference. So you should work with the reference.

With ES6 you can use the spread operator

```
const newItems = whichDeck.splice(0, howMany)
whom.push(...newItems);
```

or without ES6 you can do it with

```
var newItems = whichDeck.splice(0, howMany)
whom.push.apply(whom, newItems)
```

---

```js
let playerDeck1 = []
let playerDeck2 = []
let remainingCards = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]

const deal = (playerDeck, pile, drawCount) => {
  const newItems = pile.splice(0, drawCount)  // remove top N cards from the deck
  playerDeck.push(...newItems);  // put them on the end of the players current hand
}

console.group("turn1")
deal(playerDeck1, remainingCards, 5)  // 1,2,3,4,5
deal(playerDeck2, remainingCards, 5)  // 6,7,8,9,10
console.log("player1", JSON.stringify(playerDeck1))
console.log("player2", JSON.stringify(playerDeck2))
console.groupEnd("turn1")


console.group("turn2")
deal(playerDeck1, remainingCards, 2) // 1,2,3,4,5 + 11,12
deal(playerDeck2, remainingCards, 2) // 6,7,8,9,10 + 13,14
console.log("player1", JSON.stringify(playerDeck1))
console.log("player2", JSON.stringify(playerDeck2))
console.groupEnd("turn2")

console.group("turn3")
deal(playerDeck1, remainingCards, 2) // 1,2,3,4,5,11,12 + 15,16
deal(playerDeck2, remainingCards, 2) // 6,7,8,9,10,13,14 + 17,18
console.log("player1", JSON.stringify(playerDeck1))
console.log("player2", JSON.stringify(playerDeck2))
console.groupEnd("turn3")
```

Comment: I am trying to fully understand this.  Incase I missed something theoretical. (which become theoretic rhetorical often in my case).
I rewrote it a bit, and I still have the problem of having sepparate hands.

`function drawDeckAgain(whom, whichDeck, howMany) {
 const player1Hand = whichDeck.splice(0, howMany)
 whom.push(...player1Hand);
 console.log(player1Hand);
}

drawDeckAgain(player1Hand, genericDeck, 2);
drawDeckAgain(player1Hand, genericDeck, 1);`

sorry total mess.. have to figure out how to structure this.

Comment: well if I understand the issues, the issue is you are using the same hand for separate hands?

Comment: yes. rather than having 1 hand with both results I am having 2 different hands at 2 different times.  but I think i got the ES6 solution fixed you alluded too.  
`function drawDeckAgain(whom, whichDeck, howMany) {
 let player1Hand = whichDeck.splice(0, howMany)
 whom.push(...player1Hand);
 console.log(whom);
}

drawDeckAgain(player1Hand, genericDeck, 2);
drawDeckAgain(player1Hand, genericDeck, 1);`

this now on the 2nd drawDeckagain  now has 1 hand with 3 cards instead of a hand with 1 card.   thank you...  I really appreciate the ES6   spread opperator mention..  thank you man

Comment: essentially I am then taking `whom` and spreading the array `player1Hand` into it  and now `whom` holds all 3 cards no noNO NO  thats not it because when i console.log(whom)  I am getting an error so `whom` is temp  when i `console.log(player1Hand)`  i then get the value of an array of 3  perfect so what I state above but inreverse   I am taking player1Hand and then casually making that `whom` and then spreading `player1Hand` into itself as `whom` and then `player1Hand` is now  folded intoself or spread intself via `whom`  I think i got it.

Comment: I added an example to my game showing adding two cards after they are dealt 5 to start.

Comment: I think I am fully grasping this now under the hood.  sorry. I ask too many questions  strength and weakness. (:  thanks for patience!

Comment: `function drawDeckAgain(whom, whichDeck, howMany) {
 let currentHand = whichDeck.splice(0, howMany)
 whom.push(...currentHand);
 console.log(whom);
}
`
with a div `<div onclick="drawDeckAgain(playersArray.player1.player1Hand, genericDeck, 1)">Draw from deck</div>` 

check and check  thank you for the wisdom. truly appreciated

Comment: follow up question.  Is this  `whom.push(...currentHand)`  spread a better technique  than concat? (I suppose I am not allowed to ask about what is better as it being  objective from time to time.)

Answer (score 0):

```
let player1Hand = [];



function drawDeck(whom, whichDeck, howMany) {
    whom = whom.concat(whichDeck.splice(0, howMany));
    console.log(whom);
    player1Hand = whom;
}

drawDeck(player1Hand, genericDeck, 2);
drawDeck(player1Hand, genericDeck, 2);
```

I just rubber ducked myself...  inside the function is temporary I need to then re asses the value of player1Hand by having it then point back out of the scope of the function.  so the 2nd time its run, player1Hand value had been changed to the first itteration...
sorry.  maybe this will help someone else at some point.

Comment: solution is rather poor in my eyes. You be better off not using concat which returns a new array.

Answer (score 0):

```
  whom = whom.concat(whichDeck.splice(0, howMany));
```

that rewrites the *reference* stored into the local variable `whom` with a new array. It does not change the passed in reference or the outer variable in any way. therefore, `playerHand1` does not change. Instead you could spread into `Array.push` to actually mutate the passed array:

```
 whom.push(...whichDeck.splice(0, howMany));
```

or just return the new array:

```
return whom.concat(whichDeck.splice(0, howMany));
```

and then store that in `playerHand1`:

```
  playerHand1 = drawDeck(playerHand1, genericDeck, 2);
```

Comment: exactly.  I forgot scope.  player1Hand was only temporarily given a value of more than just an empty array.   just long enough for it to console.log the value.  then aftewards it became an empty array again.  so the 2nd drawDeck() was only dealing with an empty array again.  bingo.  (i am up voting you.. but i don't have enough clout yet) (you put in words far better than I)

Comment: @smw no, the local variable `whom` does change (which you log), but the outer `playerHand1` does not change at all! It is always an empty array.

Comment: so to understand specifically.  whom had the temporary value. which I console.logged and player1Hand was always an empty array.  until however I then have player1Hand = whom;  then player1Hand is no longer an empty array correct?  (i am just trying to dot my T and cross my i  in the theory department.. I hate stating things wrongly)

Comment: @smw yes in the code of your answer you actually change it here: `player1Hand = whom;`